# Lubuntu IP conflict

Tags: ubuntu, networking, wifi, windows, ip

I have this friend who recently installed Lubuntu on his Asus Netbook to try it out.

Problem is that even though he can find all network connections and after trying to connect to two of them (giving password etc.) nothing happens and he cannot connect to the net.

I'm assuming there is nothing wrong with both his net adapter or the networks trying to connect as well. I was looking for the Ubuntu equivalent commands of Windows like `ipconfig` `ipconf -release` `-renew` which might help but I haven't yet found a clear answer.

**Edit:**

It took me some time but as it seems that there is a problem with the gateway access, since the command `ip route show` shows nothing.

How can I fix this and then proceed to establishing a connection?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Without some error output, it is very difficult to discern what might be happening. In particular, the output of `dmesg` and the error logs of whatever network manager your friend is using would be very helpful in the troubleshooting effort.

Comment: What makes you think this is an IP conflict? That only happens when you aren't using DHCP, and something like `ipconf -release` is about DHCP. Is the wifi adapter actually supported under Linux? Are there any error messages? What is the connection status in the menu bar? How does he try to connect to the net and what happens — requests never come back, an error appears (what), …?

Comment: @Gilles Ip conflict might not be accurate but please see the edit part in the question. It might help

Comment: @HalosGhost Is the new edit I made helpful at all to understand what the problem might be?

Comment: The first thing I'd suspsect, with what you've reported so far, is still that the interface isn't up. Tell us the output of `ifconfig` — at least, what interfaces does it report, and what IP addresses does it give for each?

Comment: @GIlles don't get me wrong but as I mentioned earlier I am not doing this process, or in my laptop and therefore it takes time to report back. I am not that bad at asking questions. Patience plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see if the interface got a IP address, using `ip addr show` or `ifconfig`

```
# ip addr show
...
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:24:d7:ae:dc:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.8/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
       valid_lft 3596sec preferred_lft 3596sec
    inet6 fe80::224:d7ff:feae:dc64/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

If you do have IP, make sure you have a gateway address as well,

```
# ip route show
default via 10.0.0.138 dev em1  proto static  metric 1024 
10.0.0.0/24 dev em1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.1 
10.0.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.8
```

In that case my GW is 10.0.0.138, make use you can communicate with it,

```
# ping 10.0.0.138
PING 10.0.0.138 (10.0.0.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.138: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.293 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.138: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=2.35 ms
```

then check if you have a DNS servers, in my case i'm using a local DNS server for caching, in your case this should be you the GW address or your ISP DNS servers.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

try to make a DNS query to see if the communication with you DNS servers works,

```
dig www.google.com
-- or --
nslookup www.google.com
```

This should give you a basic idea where the problem can be.

**Edit #1:**

If you are missing a GW address, and your machine is configured to receive it IP from a DHCP server, you should try and set a static IP address and default gateway, to see if the problem is in your DHCP server.

Comment: Great thanks. It will take some time though to fix it like this since we are trying to do it remotely the old-fashioned way, via sms..

Comment: please look at the edit part of the question. We have some improvement